# Load jQuery popup on page load using url data?

Tags: php, jquery

Alright, just in case my title isn't good enough. I have my jQuery popup which works if someone clicks the link on the page. However, if I sent a link to a users email (an unsubscribe link), can I open that popup on page load only in that instance? I don't want the popup to load every time the page loads...only when the GET=gogo

I was thinking something like this:

**The Email Link:**
www.someurl.com/index.php?unsubscribe=gogo

```
$code = $_GET['unsubscribe'];
if ($code) {
   //load jQuery popup
}
```

Could something like this work?

Comment: It would easy for us to help you if you can show us your code. Whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simple attach a click event to your selector, something along these lines

```
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
    $(thisHash).trigger('click');      
}
```

this uses hashes instead of get post data

so your url would look something like this

http://domain.com/#unsubscribe